# AngularJS - Wrapping nested <select> in a <div> in a form makes its control not be bind anymore

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing a kind of select2 but with much less functionality and we want the form that is above to know about this Control (so we can use $dirty and $invalid).
But I've noted that if you wrap the select that is in the directive's HTML with a div, the $dirty and $invalid of that control stop working. Any idea why ?

Try it out on this http://plnkr.co/edit/UV425G2SMcqRYeX2N4qw?p=preview, go to the select.html file and turn

```
<select class='form-control' ng-model='selectedval' ng-attr-name='{{name}}' ng-options='item as item.name for item in options' required><option value=''>-- select --</option></select>
```

into

```
<div>
  <select class='form-control' ng-model='selectedval' ng-attr-name='{{name}}' ng-options='item as item.name for item in options' required><option value=''>-- select --</option></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I asked this as well in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6862 and got this answer by @caitp:

> So your test case is actually running an old version of angular, which
>   A) does not support the ng-attr-* directives, and B) has a broken
>   isolate scope implementation.
>
> This is still broken, but in different ways, using angular 1.2.15. You
>   have a priority issue with the ng-attr-name directive, regardless of
>   where the  control is, and so it gets added to the form
>   control with the name you aren't expecting.
>
> The reason this "works" with 1.0.8 and without wrapping it in a div,
>   is because with replace: true in your directive, we merge the
>   attributes from the directive's compile node (which does contain
>   name="...") into the root node of the template, so you're sort of
>   accidentally taking advantage of a poorly documented behaviour of the
>   compiler, in that case.
>
> Unfortunately, there isn't really a good way to have dynamic form
>   control names yet (and this is really the root of the problem you're
>   having), there are a number of PRs adding support for this, and I've
>   written a hack to decorate the ngModel controller to make this work
>   (although it might not work anymore, depending on if the new
>   $interpolate api landed yet or not), you can see that at
>   http://plnkr.co/edit/hSMzWC?p=preview
>
> So, Matias has an alternative solution for this, it's not clear which
>   one is going to land --- but in any case, that's about what your issue
>   is.
>
> In the future it would be good to ask about these on
>   http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=angularjs or
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular to get answers to
>   these kinds of support questions (this is not a bug, per se, although
>   the "issue" you're seeing might be documented better, so PRs welcome
>   for clarifying that in the compiler docs).